# I have an ArrayList that contains an ArrayList<Integer>. I am having trouble removing elements from the ArrayList<Integer>

Tags: java, arraylist

The "gamePiles" ArrayList stores "coin" ArrayLists. I am writing a method to remove a given amount of coins for a chosen index of the gamePiles ArrayList. However, the following method results in the removal of coins from all gamePile elements.

```
public class game(){
private  ArrayList<Integer> Coins = new ArrayList<Integer>();
private  ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> gamePiles = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
```

I initialize with the makePiles() method below

```
public void makePiles(){
    for(int i=0; i<arbitrary; i++){
        Coins.add(i);
    }
    System.out.println("initial amount of coins " + Coins.size());
    for(int z = 0; z < arbitraryPiles; z++){
        gamePiles.add(Coins);
    }
    System.out.println("this many piles " + gamePiles.size());
}
```

The displayPiles() method shows the piles and coins on the screen

```
public void displayPiles(){
    for(int i=0; i < gamePiles.size(); i++){
        int z = i+1;
        System.out.print("Pile " + z + ": ");
        for(int y =0; y < gamePiles.get(i).size(); y++){
            //System.out.print(y + 1);
            System.out.print("  "+gamePiles.get(i).get(y));
        }
        System.out.println();
    }       
}
```

Below is the line that calls the method

```
game.removeCoinsFromPile(int pile, int coins)
```

The for loop below does not simply remove the "last" elements from the chosen pile. 
It removes the last elements from all piles in the gamePiles ArrayList. I want it to only remove the coins from the chosen pile.

```
public void removeCoinsFromPile(int pile, int coins) {
    int last = gamePiles.get(pile).size() - 1;
    for(int i = coins; i > 0; i--) {        
        gamePiles.get(pile).remove(last);
        last--;
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to remove a specified amount, starting from the end of the list.

Comment: Could you show the code calling this method.

Comment: And show the code which is populating the `gamePiles`. My guess is that it contains references to the **same** `ArrayList<Integer>`. So deleting from one index affects all...

Comment: I think the problem is when you instantiate the gamePiles, maybe you are adding to gamePiles always the same object.

Comment: I don't get exact problem could you brief what you are trying to achieve and where are you failing so that I can or any body else can Help you

Comment: I believe you are right. I am adding the same object to gamePiles. What would you suggest be done to accomplish what I am trying to do, which is set up an arbitrary number of piles and coins.

Comment: You have only one pile, referenced multiple times. Create multiple lists. Also, you only have a single count, not multiple items-all you need is a list of ints, not a list of lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your elements in `gamePiles` are referring to the same list. When you change one of them, they all will change because they are referring to the exact same list.

Try replacing this:

```
for(int z = 0; z < arbitraryPiles; z++){
    gamePiles.add(Coins);
}
```

with this:

```
for(int z = 0; z < arbitraryPiles; z++){
  gamePiles.add(new ArrayList<>(Coins));
}
```

This will create a fresh copy of the `Coins` list for each element in `gamePiles`.

Comment: I got a list of errors that more or less resemble this: java.lang.object cannot be converted to java.util.ArrayList

Comment: Also, if earlier Java than 7, you'll need `gamePiles.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(Coins))`.

Comment: That did it! Thanks! I'm new to programming and did not realize that I was referencing the same object the whole time. I appreciate the help.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the same pile of coins in a list of piles. You should make a new pile for each list, something like this:

```
    for(int z = 0; z < arbitraryPiles; z++){
     for(int i=0; i<arbitrary; i++){
            coins.add(i);
        }
        System.out.println("initial amount of coins " + coins.size());

        gamePiles.add(coins);
    }

System.out.println("this many piles " + gamePiles.size());
```

Of course `arbitrary` variable should be set for each iteration of an inner loop if you don't want to generate lists with the same size.